# Why is my key-value evaluation failing in bash?

Tags: bash, debugging

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
location=LOCATION
function status (){
    therestformat="%t(%f)%20%p"
    declare -A icons=(
        ["?"]  ="???" #unknown
        ["o"]  ="  " #sunny
        ["m"]  ="  " #partly cloudy
        ["mm"] =" " #cloudy
        ["mmm"]="" #very cloudy
        ["="]  ="" #fog
        ["///"]="  " #heavy rain
        ["//"] =" " #heavy showers
        ["**"] ="  " #heavy snow
        ["*/"] =" " #heavy snow showers
        ["/"]  ="  " #light rain
        ["."]  =" " #light showers
        ["x"]  ="l  " #light sleet
        ["x/"] ="l " #light sleet showers
        ["*"]  ="  " #light snow
        ["*/"] =" " #light snow showers
        ["/!/"]=" " #thundery heavy rain
        ["!/"] ="" #thundery showers
        ["*!*"]="" #thundery snow showers
    )
    echo $(curl -s "wttr.in/$location?format=%x")
    conditionplain=$(curl -s "wttr.in/$location?format=%x")
    conditionicon=${icons[conditionplain]}
    therest=$(curl -s "wttr.in/$location?format=$therestformat")
    echo "$therest ${icons[conditionplain]}"
}
function leftclick () {
    curl -s "wttr.in/$location" | less -R
}
function rightclick () {
    curl -s "v2.wttr.in/$location" | less -R
}

case "$1" in
    s) status ;;
    l) leftclick ;;
    r) rightclick ;;
esac
```

Bash is giving me a really weird bug today.
`curl -s wttr.in/LOCATION?format=%x` definitely returns a condition in that table, but applying `conditionicon=${icons[conditionplain]}` gives me what appears to be an empty string.

I've tried messing with quotes, brackets, etc - but the error persists.

Comment: I suspect there's a `\r` or `\r\n` at the end of `$conditionplain`

Comment: You can't index associative arrays with variable names. Try `conditionicon=${icons[$conditionplain]}` instead.

Comment: Use `echo "$conditionplain" | od -c` to see what's in it.

Comment: Surprise, it ends in \n. The array call is fixed too.
There's all sorts of ways to remove the trailing \n, but none of them seem to work. I've tried perl chomp, echo -n, and tr -d "\n".

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space preceding the equals sign:

```
        ["?"]  ="???" #unknown
```

Newer versions of bash consider `["?"]` the key and `="???"` the value instead of `?` and `???` as you intended. This behavior is documented in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) as follows:

> When assigning to an associative array, the words in a compound assignment may be either assignment statements, for which the subscript is required, or a list of words that is interpreted as a sequence of alternating keys and values: `name=(key1 value1 key2 value2 … )`. These are treated identically to `name=( [key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 … )`.

So either remove the space

```
        ["?"]="???" #unknown
```

or use the alternate form

```
        "?"  "???" #unknown
```